# Encrypting App.config file when app is installed in Program Files

Tags: .net, encryption, connection-string, app-config

I have an app that will not run if the connection string in app.config is encrypted AND the app is installed in Program Files. The connection string section is encrypted as a post build event so it is deployed already encrypted.  I know there are limits on what an app can do when installed in Program Files, but I don't understand why this is one of the limitations.

Comment: Are you using built-in configuration encryption? This uses either the current user or current machine key, making it undeployable. You have to encrypt it on the target machine.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain Good catch. I misread the OP's post to infer he encrypted as a post *install* event, not a post *build* event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it has more to do with the permissions implied by the identity associated with the process *executing* the application, eg permissions to key store, or the app.config file itself.

Per the observation from @JulienLebosquain, if you have configured encryption as a post-*build* event, machine-specific keys will have been used to perform the encryption, thus making it unrecoverable on any *other* machine. To accomplish post-install encryption on an app.config file, you would have to consider constructing a Setup project and adding an Installer class to your application that defines a post-install event that performs encryption based on host machine keys.

Comment: +1  Question In that scenario could they not hack the setup file or stall the install to access the connection string?

Comment: There is certainly an interval during which the unencrypted configuration file is present on the disk. That creates an opportunity, however brief, to capture the unencrypted data. The data could also be hacked if the machine keys were compromised, or even beyond that if someone hooked into the application with a debugger and examined live memory post-decryption (unless the string is stored with a SecureString).